# Using g_serial to emulate FTDI

Tags: serial-port, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, usbserial, ftdi

**Situation:**

We have a custom PID utilized by a customized FTDI driver for our hardware devices. Now we're attempting to use a BBB and remove any need for FTDI silcone hardware altogether, yet utilize our customized driver. I'm attempting to emulate an FTDI device with a BBB using g_serial. I've used the following command on a debian based BBB:

```
modprobe g_serial idVendor=0x0403 idProduct=0x6001 use_acm=1
```

I've successfully got it to be recognized as an FTDI part "USB Serial Converter" by windows, but fails to be enumerated as a COM port after that. Plus, after a few minutes it will BSOD windows.I assume this is because of a fault between handshakes and/or protocols causing windows to wink out.

**Question**:

Can anyone offer any advice on this situation or any references that may help me along my path? I've attempted reviewing most documentation I could find but nothing seems to offer any real use.

I also thought about utilizing the ftdi_sio module in a custom fashion for the task, but haven't gotten that far yet.

***Any assistance and/or reference material would be much appreciated!***